# Wordpress list the_content() in loop (several page entries)

Tags: wordpress, loops

I wish to build a wordpress template in which the whole content of several sub-pages is displayed, one after the other.

```
 <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>

                        </article>


                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php else: ?>


                            <p>No Entries.</p>


                    <?php endif; ?>
```

My template now shows me, as I hoped

- The Title
- The Excerpt
- But **not** the (whole) page content of the entries in my loop.

What's the matter? And how can it be done?

Comment: This may work:
I have managed to create a new WP_Query() which shows me the entire content of several blog posts. This code is wirtten inside my taxonomy template file. I now wish to display the taxonomy matches one after the other, rather than blog posts.

Comment: This works for posts as I want: `<?php
global $post;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 23 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>     `. When I add `'post_type' => 'portfolio',` to the arguments, The content area is not showing as it did for blog posts. :(